# How to render a view in a form

Tags: 7, forms

I am building a configuration form in an admin menu.  I'll have some input fields inline at top, and below, a table of data.  I'd like to render a view of the data in the table so it can handle the paging, etc.

How can I access the view and render it?

Comment: I am not clear with the question, but if you want to show view with table then you can check the display setting in view.  If you look at the code of render() function it is calling the drupal_render() function only but it will show the top level elements as well.

Comment: I modified my post.  I want to render a view in the #markup field in my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `view_embedd_view` function and you will get the view.

```
$output = views_embed_view($viewName,$display_id);
print $output;
```